# Что означает background-image: url('data:...')?

Tags: css

меня интересует то что написано зелеными буквами background-image: url( *вот тут* )

```css
.custom-checkbox:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #0b76ef;
  background-color: #0b76ef;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Comment: Backgroung-image: url эта запись означает что векторное изображение (svg) конвертнули в формат base64 (такой формат позволяет просто вот так в css изображение в строку приобразовать )  при это векторность не теряется

Comment: @SergBakay, только это не base64 формат. Это формат data URL,

Comment: угощайтесь :3 [Data URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL)

Answer (score 0):

> меня интересует то что написано зелеными буквами `Backgroung-image: url( вот тут )`

Это должно было быть в теле вопроса.

---

`data:image` - [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs), позволяющее встраивать небольшие медиафайлы, без обращения к ним по HTTP.
`/svg+xml` - даёт понять, что работать придётся именно с SVG форматом, плюсом XML.

Далее после запятой идёт код SVG, которому применено кодирование.
Есть инструмент который [конвертит SVG код](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/), по нему можно и декодировать данное изображение, в вашем оно вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]